# Amplify Graphql schema problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have issues when creating a schema for Amplify/graphql. I have one type called Employee and one type called Station. An Employee can work on multiple stations and vice versa. Which alternative do you think I should choose?

1. Here I simply look for the station ids and create an array as station ids. No real connection.

```
type Station @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  stationName: String!
  id: ID 
}

type Employee @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID
  employeeName: String!
  stationIds: [String] 
}
```

2. I tried this but had problems register the stations field in Employees. Tried some custom inputs but I am not sure how to do it.

```
type Station @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  stationName: String!
  id: ID
}

type Employee @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID
  employeeName: String!
  stations: [Station] 
}
```

3. My current solution but I don't know if its overkill?

```
type Station @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  stationName: String!
  id: ID
  employees: [Employee] @manyToMany(relationName: "StationEmployee")
}

type Employee @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID
  employeeName: String!
  stations: [Station] @manyToMany(relationName: "StationEmployee")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution (3) appears to be correct based on the [Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#many-to-many-relationship)

I'd also recommend making the `ID` non-nullable for both types, i.e. 'ID!'

In your first solution you used a SQL-like pattern by referring to *IDs* instead of *types*, `stationIds: [String]` is a counter-pattern in GraphQL since you require multiple queries to get all the results you wanted and you'd have to stitch them together by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will use this. I see that a new table was created and it is called EmployeeStations table and I use this table when I register a new station for an employee. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: That sounds correct.